# jQuery mobile, html5 phone links with javascript instead

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a split-button list in jQuery mobile, and I notice I can't have links inside of my buttons without some strange formatting happening.

Because of this, a phone link I would normally write as:

```
<a href="tel+1234567898">123-456-7898</a>
```

I am trying to do with a bit of javascript:

```
$('.phone').bind('click', function() {
    var phone = $(this).attr('data-phone');
    window.location = "tel:+" + phone;
});
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<span data-email="<?php echo $phone; ?>" class="phone"><?php echo $phone; ?></span>
```

This is recognized "in the browser" (Chrome asks me if I want to open communicator) but doesn't appear to work in an iPhone...

**Edit:**

Split button lists work like this:

```
<li><a href="some-link">Content</a><a href="another-link"></a></li>
```

So if you put a link phone into the first part ("some-link") it's invalid HTML (maybe?) and so jQuery mobile takes out all the content inside of  so I can't just seem to change the CSS to fix this.

Comment: Sounds like you're solving a CSS problem with JS.

Comment: In my experience, iOS converts any strings of appropriate length/makeup into href tel links without any formal mark up? As in <span>911</span> will automatically be recognised by the device as a telephone number and be made actionable.

Comment: @Mathletics I know, right? But you should see the extra styles this framework adds...I'll take another look at it.

Comment: @Ryan I just tried <span>2223339999</span> but it doesn't work. Do you need to have dashes in the phone number for it to be recognized?

Comment: Go to hsjdental.com on any iOS device, scroll to the bottom to see the footer where the practice's number is automatically detected, no extra mark up.

Comment: Right ignore my comments, I didn't realise it was a jQuery Mobile issue, have added an answer that should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html) Apple's docs RE URL tel schema. jQuery Mobile is a pain at stripping/injecting tags and new elements on page load. Your solution is to update the href tag when the document is fully loaded (and when jQuery Mobile has stopped screwing around):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#phone_number").attr("href","tel-999");
});
```

Should work :)

Comment: OMG, thanks...I couldn't use an "a" tag so I had to swap out my span with the above, but it works, thanks so much!

Comment: No worries man! If you could mark the answer as correct that would me much appreciated :)